# Disable select drop-downs, display names only

Tags: theming, datetime

I am looking for a way to remove the select drop-downs from the datepicker popup and display only months (and the year). As for the appearance, it can be altered in datepicker.1.7.css.

How do I disable the select drop-downs and show only the names?

Comment: In short, you want to remove days from the date & you want to display only month & year. Am I right ?

Comment: Hey. Not quite. In short: Remove dropdowns and only display month-name and year. User navigates only via arrows.

Comment: Check this first : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229654/creating-date-field-with-only-month-and-year-drupal

Comment: Unfortunately this does not show, how to hide the select-fields and use an alternative display instead. But it definitely points me to the right files!

Answer (score 1):

As of date_popup 7.x-2.9, you can do this in your theme or custom module, implementing `hook_element_info_alter(&$type)`.

```
function mytheme_element_info_alter(&$type) {
  $type['date_popup']['#datepicker_options'] += array(
    'changeMonth' => FALSE,
    'changeYear' => FALSE,
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Did it. Turns out, that you can influence the datepicker options in modules/date/data_popup/date_popup.module. In the function date_popup_element_info you can influence the datepicker-options for the jquery-part. This means that:

```
'#datepicker_options' => array(
  'changeMonth' => FALSE,
  'changeYear' => FALSE
),
```

will disable the dropdowns. However remember: This is a system wide change and might be gone with the next update.

Comment: You'd be much better changing the form using `hook_form_alter` as hacking contributed module code is, as you point out, a recipe for disaster over time.